# In Zombie Panic Source, what effect do guns have on running speed?

Tags: zombie-panic-source

In the PC game Zombie Panic Source which is a half Life 2 modification. The player starts with 0 bars of fatiuge and faster running than zombies. Presumably, you also achieve a quicker rate of fatigue when carrying more stuff.

How is the running speed determined by what weapons and/or ammo you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the [forum](http://www.zombiepanic.org/forums/showthread.php?t=8068),

> "Every weapon/item/ammo picked up lowers a survivor's movement speed
>   (shown as velocity in the cl_showpos 1 command) by a certain amount.
>   The amount is simple addition or subtraction, if a survivor with
>   nothing, speed 195, picks up a sledgehammer, it would lower his speed
>   by 14.5, making his new speed 180.5. Guns have two numbers, the
>   left-side number is the empty weight of the gun, the right-side number
>   is the weight of the gun fully loaded."

There is a link [here](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y21/Skarth/WeaponsWeightGuide.png), where all of the weapons, ammo, and equipment (and the amount of weight they add) are neatly listed. ^_^